# Use Jquery's jConfirm like JS's confirm method

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, javascript

I have an anchor on click of which I want to call jquery's `jconfirm` method and I am having problem in using it directly as I would do for `confirm` method in javascript

```
<a id="ctl00_CPHMain_lnkDeleteImage" name="ctl00$CPHMain$lnkDeleteImage" 
    onclick="return confirm('Are you sure ?');">Test</a>
```

And in jquery I am doing it like this

```
<a id="ctl00_CPHMain_lnkDeleteImage" name="ctl00$CPHMain$lnkDeleteImage" 
         onclick="return jConfirm('Are you sure?', 'Update Test')">Test</a>
```

I want my anchor click to occur when user selects `ok` in `confirm window`

currently I have done it like this in `ASP.NET`

```
function ConfirmWindow() {
            jConfirm("Are you sure?", "Update Test", function(r) {
                if (r == true) {
                    __doPostBack("ctl00$CPHMain$lnkDeleteImage", "");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }

<a onclick="return ConfirmWindow()" id="ctl00_CPHMain_lnkDeleteImage" 
       name="ctl00$CPHMain$lnkDeleteImage" >Test</a>
```

Comment: jConfirm is not made to work like that, please understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  The JavaScript/DOM `confirm` dialog is truly [modal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window), which means that it halts script execution and user interaction until the user responds by clicking a button in the confirm dialog.

*jConfirm*, however, is a JavaScript implementation that overlays the current page content with more content, so it's **not modal** because it can't halt script execution without blocking user interaction with the "dialog" itself.  This means it has to return from the function before the user can respond to the confirm dialog and that's why the callback function is required instead.